# Why it doesn't create a table in database if you don't declare a primary key?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, jdbc

Using JDBC,

This code works when I declare that "id" field is a primary key.

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION1 " +
             "(id INTEGER not NULL, " +
             " first VARCHAR(255), " + 
             " last VARCHAR(255), " + 
             " age INTEGER, " + 
             " PRIMARY KEY (id))";
stmt.executeUpdate (sql);
```

But when I remove the declaration `PRIMARY KEY (id)` and the `not NULL` tags.

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION2 " +
             "(id INTEGER, " +
             " first VARCHAR(255), " + 
             " last VARCHAR(255), " + 
             " age INTEGER");
stmt.executeUpdate (sql);
```

Comment: @MahmoudEskandari english please?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder my bad, what about primary key?

Comment: No need for your edit just now, you were right, it didn't compile -- because of the change at the *end* of the statement (I was looking at the change near the beginning).

Comment: When you tried to compile this, the compiler would have output the error **with an arrow pointing right at the problem `)`**, like this: http://pastie.org/8691601. How was that not sufficiently clear?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no it didn't produce this kind of error. it thrown exceptions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Programmers don't read error messages anyway these days. They just look at the red icon in their IDE which means "there is an error".

Comment: @FahadSiddiqui it probably caused an exception because you use eclipse and executed the program despite the compilation errors, ignoring the warning dialog box that eclipse displayed. Don't try to execute code that doesn't compile. It will never work. And read the error messages from the compiler.

Comment: @JBNizet wouldn't do such mistake again. lesson learnt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't compile because you have a trailing parenthese that shouldn't be there:

```
" age INTEGER");
```

should be

```
" age INTEGER)";
```

It has nothing to do with the content of the SQL string, which the Java compiler doesn't care about.

Note that reading the error message from the compiler helps identifying what and where the error is. You should read the message, and post it if you can't understand it, instead of incorrectly guessing what the problem might be.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was a blunder.

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis is outside the string query. Which constructing and passing a wrong string for processing .

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION2 " +
             "(id INTEGER, " +
             " first VARCHAR(255), " + 
             " last VARCHAR(255), " + 
             " age INTEGER)";


   System.out.println("Sql Query is ="+sql);
    //Now Execute you query here
```

You can also find the exact error/exception if you print the sql query before executing.This print statement will show you the exact query you are going to execute.

Hope it will help you.